# Mimetype detection - What is the purpose of & 0xff in this code?

Tags: java, bitwise-and

The following is an excerpt from code used to detect the mime type of a file using magic numbers.

I can understand that hexadecimal is the focus here.

However, why use `int`s and why the bitwise AND with 0xFF ?

```
    byte[] header = new byte[11];
    System.arraycopy(data, 0, header, 0, Math.min(data.length, header.length));
    int c1 = header[0] & 0xff;
    int c2 = header[1] & 0xff;
    int c3 = header[2] & 0xff;
    int c4 = header[3] & 0xff;
    int c5 = header[4] & 0xff;
    int c6 = header[5] & 0xff;
    int c7 = header[6] & 0xff;
    int c8 = header[7] & 0xff;
    int c9 = header[8] & 0xff;
    int c10 = header[9] & 0xff;
    int c11 = header[10] & 0xff;

    if (c1 == 0xCA && c2 == 0xFE && c3 == 0xBA && c4 == 0xBE) // CAFEBABE
    {
        return "application/java-vm";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `byte` is a signed type.  For example, `0xFF` as a `byte` is actually -1 as an `int`.   The result is that `(byte) 0xFF != 0xFF`, which can be confusing.  So when trying to treat `byte` values as unsigned when converting them to `int`, you should always write `myByte & 0xFF` to ensure that the sign isn't extended when you don't want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

`& 0xff` is setting upper bits to 0 and just considering last 8 bits

Answer (score 1):

```
header[0] & 0xff;
```

Is masking the bits to only generate 8 bits/ 2bytes.

why??

**memory wise**, instead of wasting  8 bits they are only using 8 bits from the 16bits unsigned two's compliment of int.